# Flutter selectable text on all table

Tags: flutter, jquery-ui-selectable

I know that there is a SelectableText widget but what I am looking for is something to make an entire table/page to be selectable, not text by text but the entire table, like a normal page in html.

By the way: I am developing web pages with flutter

Is there any way to do it using the lastest version of flutter/dart or any 3 part widget?

Thanks

Comment: Did you get this working?

Comment: Sorry the delay but I didn't make it yet, don't know how